# How does the HOTP dynamic truncation function generalize to longer hashes?

Tags: hmac, reference-request, sha-256, sha-512, hotp

HOTP, the HMAC-based One-Time Password algorithm from [RFC 4226](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4226.txt), uses a "dynamic truncation" function to turn the 20 byte HMAC-SHA-1 value into a 31 bit string. The dynamic truncation (from Section 5.3) works like this (and [is probably useless](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/5259/13625)):

```
 DT(String) // String = String[0]...String[19]
 Let OffsetBits be the low-order 4 bits of String[19]
 Offset = StToNum(OffsetBits) // 0 <= OffSet <= 15
 Let P = String[OffSet]...String[OffSet+3]
 Return the Last 31 bits of P
```

TOTP ([RFC 6238](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6238.txt)) allows using SHA-256 and SHA-512 as the HMAC hash in HOTP, but doesn't seem to define a new dynamic truncation function for use with them:

> TOTP implementations MAY use HMAC-SHA-256 or HMAC-SHA-512 functions,
>     based on SHA-256 or SHA-512 [SHA2] hash functions, instead of the
>     HMAC-SHA-1 function that has been specified for the HOTP computation
>     in [RFC4226].

Should I use low 4 bits of `String[19]` as offset, low 4 bits of `String[length-1]`, or perhaps some other number of bits or a completely different truncation algorithm?

Comment: If you wanted to replicate it, use String[length-1] and do the low 4 bits of SHA-256 or low 5 bits of SHA-512... however the truncation method is probably useless with a well engineered hash function, and fixed LSB or MSB truncation is acceptable.

Comment: @RichieFrame, I agree that it's useless and I could do away with it if I didn't care about compatibility. However, I would like to be able to just say "uses TOTP" rather than having to justify the change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to find it out by reproducing the test vectors.

TL;DR: The standard assumes that you use the low 4 bits of the last byte of the hash, regardless of its length. So replace 19 in the original DT definition with 31 for SHA-256 or 63 for SHA-512 and you are good to go.

---

Finding this out wasn't *completely* straightforward, as the standard only has a single test secret listed:

> The test token shared secret uses the ASCII string value
>      "12345678901234567890".  With Time Step X = 30, and the Unix epoch as
>      the initial value to count time steps, where T0 = 0, the TOTP
>      algorithm will display the following values for specified modes and
>      timestamps.

If fact, to reproduce the test vector values for SHA-256 and SHA-512 you have to extend that secret to 32/64 characters. I.e. use the ASCII strings "12345678901234567890123456789012" and "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234" instead.